# Passing non-static data members as default arguments to methods

Tags: c++

My class has methods which could be useful in various cases so I want them to be parameter independent. Code:

**.h**

```
std::string integerPart;
std::string remainderPart;
void removeZeroesFromBeginning(std::string &str = integerPart);
void removeZeroesFromEnd(std::string &str = remainderPart);
```

**.cpp**

```
void UltimateNumber::removeZeroesFromBeginning(string &str){...}
void UltimateNumber::removeZeroesFromEnd(string &str){...}
```

How should I declare it? Everything I tried gave me compilation errors.

Comment: Pray tell oh great one - what are those errors

Comment: @EdHeal **error: invalid use of non-static data member 'UltimateNumber::integerPart'
     void removeZeroesFromBeginning(std::string &str = integerPart);**

Comment: @Ron I don't know exactly how they called.. Maybe object parameters, members, fields or so.. In this case it's **integerPart** and
**remainderPart;**

Comment: Are you asking if you can define default function arguments to be members of your class?

Comment: Well follow the error message - make them static

Comment: @StoryTeller yeah, I want to pass it if no value was passed.

Comment: @EdHeal I can't. Every object must have their own.

Comment: Please supply the whole declaration of the class

Comment: It will propably be easier to just create overloads that don't have parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is overloading, not default function arguments.

```
std::string integerPart;
std::string remainderPart;

void removeZeroesFromBeginning(std::string &str);
void removeZeroesFromBeginning() {
  removeZeroesFromBeginning(integerPart);
}

void removeZeroesFromEnd(std::string &str);
void removeZeroesFromEnd() {
  removeZeroesFromEnd(remainderPart);
}
```

Overload resolution takes care of the details. Either the user passes an output argument, or you pass the class member otherwise.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear but if UltimateNumber is a class that actually represents a number, the overload with argument does not make any sense.

Comment: @KitFisto - Yeah, an output parameter and conditional memoization is kinda strange. Didn't really give it much thought when answering, I must say.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly (lots of guessing involved), I would say you should separate the implementation for the UltimateNumber class from the logical implementation of the zero removing functionality. Something along the lines of:

```
class MyFancyNumberManipulations {
public:
static void removeZeroesFromBeginnging(std::string& v);
...
};


void UltimateNumber::removeZeroesFromBeginning(string& str) {
  MyFancyNumberManipulations(integerPart);
}
```